# Download and Play Audio/Video files from server to our application using iPhone sdk

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am implementing a server based application. In that I need to Download and Play audio/video file.Is it possible to Download and Play Audio/Video files from the server to our application. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.You will need to call the url and store it in the documents directory and play the video using mediaplayer framework.However there is a risk of rejection from apple on the basis of excess bandwidth usage on cellular network.Streaming the videos using HTTP protocol is another option.